# how to resolve common error when trying to install a gem : checking for sth.(method name) in sth

Tags: ruby, windows, rubygems

error : checking for sth.(method name) in sth. *** extconf.rb failed ***
and in extconf.rb , you will see ruby method "have_library"

This error happens when lacking necessary libraries and/or headers.
I have seen this error for several times and every time it takes me a lot of time.

Can anyone tell me the basics on how to resolve this ***on windows***?
How can I manually add the necessary libraries ***on windows***?

Comment: What exactly are those errors?

Comment: Sounds largely dependant on your platform. On Linux you would start with your distro's package manager, on OS X I'd use brew, some prefer macports.